# java.awt.Desktop doesn't work

Tags: java, file, awt, desktop

My computer's system is XP and when I open files like doc, txt or ppt,this code doesn't works.I already have office2007 , but desktop.open(file) can't open any file without erro Info. And some computers can work fine , why?

```
public boolean byDesktop(String path){  
      File file = new File(path);  
      if(file.isFile()){   
       Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();  
       try {  
        desktop.open(file);  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                 System.out.println(e);  
                }  
       return true;  
      }else{  
       return false;  
      }  
     }
```

Comment: what error do you see? Please add any errors or exceptions to the question body.

Comment: You should also use function isDesktopSupported() to know if these features are available in current OS.

Comment: Call `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` and post that output instead of the `e.toString()` output.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this link in stack overflow which discusses the same thing. But please do post the error so that we'll get a better understanding.

[Facing problems with java.awt.Desktop in 64 bit JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792298/facing-problems-with-java-awt-desktop-in-64-bit-jvm)